# Find the minimum of two variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the best arrangement for n boxes (dimensions: c * d) on a platform (dimensions: a * b).
I presumed to write something like:

```
FindMinimum[(a-p*c)*(b-m*d), p, m]
```

Where p is the numbers of boxes to place on the a-side of the platform and m the same for the b side.
Why doesn't it work? (I'd like to find the numbers of boxes to place per each side of the platform.)
[image: p+m=8] 
I want to minimize the grey area

Comment: `FindMinimum` is only used for numerical computations. First try assuming that some parameters are positive and use the function `Minimize`. For example take a look at this `Assuming[
 a > 0
 , Simplify[Minimize[a*x^2, x]]
 ]`

Comment: `Minimize[(a - p*c)*(b - m*d), {p, m}]` works, but the solution (either $a b$, $0$, or $\infty$) can be readily derived from `(a - p*c)*(b - m*d) // Expand`.

Comment: 1. Can you explain the problem in more details?  I don't understand what are the possible arrangements.  2. `KnapsackSolve` (new in v11) is probably better for this sort of problem.  But I don't understand the problem, and if I'm not alone, better explanations are needed.  3. The syntax you used with `FindMinimum` is simply wrong. Don't guess and then wonder why it didn't work.  [Look it up!](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html)

Comment: Thanks you all. 1) I don't know English well 2) I'm new at Mathematica, so I beg your pardon. I want to know how many boxes can fill the platform. So, as first attempt, I try to minimize the free space left after placing these boxes on a platform, and i presumed to minimize the product of the space that will be available on the a side (a - p*c) * space available on the b side (b - m*d). I know there are other solutions but this is just a "starting point" and I want to use a function that find the minimum values.

Comment: I still don't understand, but maybe others do.  Perhaps a drawing will help.  Draw a platform and one possible arrangement.  That will make everything very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for specific examples numerically (I dont see another option since you have to specify that the number of boxes have to be integers, as far as I could interpret your picture)

```
a = 15;
b = 7;
c = 3;
d = 2;
NMinimize[
 {
  (a*b - n1*c*d - n2*c*d)^2
  , Element[n1, Integers]
   && Element[n2, Integers]
   && n1*c <= a
   && n1*d <= b
   && n2*d <= a
   && n2*c <= b
   && 0<=n1 (*additional conditions*)
   && 0<=n2
  }
 , {n1, n2}
 ]
```

> {5625., {n1 -> 3, n2 -> 2}}

The result above tells you that the error in the objective function `(a*b - n1*c*d - n2*c*d)^2` is 5625 when you use 3 boxes with their long side with length `c` parallel to the platform side with length `a` and 2 of the other boxes with length `d` parallel to `a`.

A analytical solution seems difficult since you have to consider only integers for `n1` and `n2` and they have to fulfill the conditions I also gave in the minimization.

Comment: What's the difference between n1 and n2?

Comment: `n1` is the number of boxes with side `c` parallel to `a` (take a look at the first inequality I imposed in the minimization), while `n2` is the number of boxes with side `d` parallel to `a` (connected to the third inequality).

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you very much :D

Comment: @Luca you are welcome :D since you are new, don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem. that is useful for everybody.

Comment: I want to make the assumption n1 and n2 are positive integer, what should I write? (in this moment I'm trying to implement the possibility to place boxes "tunerd", so I add n3 and n4, but it always return negative values)

Comment: @Luca I just added those conditions to the code.